# Can I use a BLS12-381 private key to sign Ethereum transactions?

Tags: cryptography, ethereum, signature, elliptic-curve, secp256k1

I'm new to cryptography and I've recently been studying BLS signatures. Please forgive me if I make any mistakes while writing.

I've tried generating a BLS key pair and using the private key to derive an Ethereum account and sign on-chain transactions. I used the '[mattrglobal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mattrglobal/bbs-signatures)' library to generate the BLS keys, and then passed the private key to the '[ethereumjs-wallet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereumjs-wallet)' library to derive an account.

```
const {
  generateBls12381G2KeyPair,
} = require("@mattrglobal/node-bbs-signatures");

const {
  default: { fromPrivateKey },
} = require("ethereumjs-wallet");

const keyPairTest = (async function () {

  const keyPair = await generateBls12381G2KeyPair();

  const wallet = fromPrivateKey(Buffer.from(keyPair.secretKey));

  console.log(`secretKey: ${Buffer.from(keyPair.secretKey).toString("hex")}`);
  console.log(`ethereum address: ${wallet.getAddressString()}`);

})();
```

Even though I was able to derive an Ethereum public key, I didn't expect to be able to sign valid Ethereum transactions, because I thought that the different curve parameters would prevent me from generating valid signatures for the transactions.

However, by directly using the private key on MetaMask (on the Sepolia testnet), I was able to perform a simple fund transfer transaction and deploy a smart contract.

How is this possible? Am I overlooking something?

It seems to me that it is generally not recommended to use the same key for two different types of signatures, is that correct?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site focuses on software development (e.g. smart contracts on Ethereum), while your question seems to be more related to cryptography. If you're unable to get answers to this specific question here, I'd recommend you to check [Cryptography StackExchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) and [Ethereum StackExchange](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice @PetrHejda , I will now make a post with the question there as well

Comment: Both BLS12381 and Ed25519 private keys are 32 bytes long, so while you can reuse the same private key you generated using the BLS library, their public keys would be much different and verification would follow different algorithms. Again, private keys are random scalars modulo p in a given curve, so you can reuse them across implementations, though this doesn't have practical applications. You can also just generate random byte array of size 32 without using a library.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use a BLS12-381 private key to sign Ethereum transactions?

No. Ethereum transactions do not use BLS12-381.

> Digital signatures in the blockchain world are usually based on elliptic curve groups. For signing users' transactions, Ethereum uses ECDSA signatures with the secp256k1 elliptic curve

[A private key is a random 256 bit number. You can use private keys on most curves](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/118705/620). When MetaMask imports your private key, it only imports a random number.